# Polynomial of degree $n$ over a field of characteristic $p>0$ has at most $n/p$ distinct roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ over a field $F$ of characteristic $p$. Suppose $f'=0$. Show that $p\mid n$ and that $f$ has at most $n/p$ distinct roots.
I can't solve this question, any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f'=0$ is equivalent to $f\in F[X^p]$, so $p\mid n$. Furthermore, $f\in F[X^p]$ implies $f(X)=g(X^p)$ where $\deg g=n/p$, so $f$ has at most $n/p$ distinct roots. (Note that $a\neq b$ implies $a^p\neq b^p$ in a field of characteristic $p>0$.)

Comment: the problem is this polynomial is not irreducible, in my book (Bhattacharya) the polynomial has to be irreducible. Thanks for your answer

Comment: calm down please, I'm just asking if we need or not this polynomial be irreducible.