# Number of distinct roots of $f(x) = x^n - d \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ in its splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

Where $d \in \mathbb{Z}_p \setminus \{ 0\}$.

I have two cases to consider: when $n \mid p$ and when $n \nmid p$.

For $n \nmid p$ I found that there are $n$ distinct roots in its splitting field, $K$, because of the relation that $$f'(x) \neq 0 \iff f(x) \text{is separable} $$

And since $n \nmid p$, $n \not \equiv 0 \ (mod \ p)$ so $f'(x)$ is not identically $0.$  I was wondering if this is correct?

For $n \mid p$ i found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251137/polynomial-of-degree-n-over-a-field-of-characteristic-p0-has-at-most-n-p), but feel uncomfortable because I haven't been exposed to polynomial rings of the form like $F[X^p]$ before, nor understand the significance of $a \neq b \implies a^p \neq b^p$ in the solution.  Also, it describes an upper bound for distincy roots, whereas the question I'm working on says to give a precise expression for the number of distinct roots in its splitting field.  I also don't understand the significance of the condition that $d \neq 0$ in my question either.  Any guidance is appreciated whether on a new approach or to clarify the linked one.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: From my understanding $F[X^p]$ would just be polynomials over $F$ of the form

$$a_0+a_1X^p+a_2X^{2p}+...+a_nX^{np}.$$

This happens if $f'$ is identically $0$. However, it need not happen if $f'$ has roots. In the splitting field of $g\in F[X^p]$ we get 'linear' factors like $(X^p-c)$. Now a nice thing about when $f(X)=g(X^p)$ is that all those factors $(X^p-c)$ of $g,$ when consider in the splitting field of $f$ over $F$ are of the form $(X-c^{1/p})^p.$ This is why we  want $a^p=b^p,$ when $a\not=b,$ otherwise $a,b$ could both be roots of $(X-c^{1/p})^p$

Comment: I get the "switcheroo" with defining $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x^p]$ in terms of $g(x^p)$ where $g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$.  Consequently, this means $f(x)$ has degree $n/p$.  I also see that if we split $f(x)$ we get factors of the form $(x^p - c)$ where $c \in \mathbb{Z}_p$.  Also we use the fact that $(a+b)^p = a^p + b^p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and that's why $a \neq b \implies a^p \neq b^p$ is important.  I don't get anything about why the number of distinct roots (i.e. the $(x^p - c) = (x -c^{1/p})^p$) in this case has to be a certain number though.

Comment: By Little Fermat $d^p=d$. So if $n=p^m n_1$ with $\gcd(n,p_1)=1$, then
$$x^n-d=(x^{n_1}-d)^{p^m}.$$ This is zero if and only of $x^{n_1}-d$ is zero. But you already covered this case, and can conclude that the number of zeros in any splitting field is $n_1$. Mind you, a similar argument works in any algebcraic extension field of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ because raising to $p$th power is a  bijection in any such field. Therefore $d=d_1^{p^m}$ in such a field, and we can use the same argument.

Comment: @Struggles apply $(a+b)^p=a^b+b^p$ to $(x-c^{1/p})^p$. What do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$f'(x) \neq 0 \iff f(x) \text{ is separable} $$

This is wrong.  This equivalence only holds when $f$ is irreducible, which your $f$ may not be.  The correct equivalence is that $f$ is separable iff $f$ and $f'$ are relatively prime (since common roots of $f$ and $f'$ are the same as repeated roots of $f$).  See where that gets you for your particular $f$ (here you will need to use the assumption that $d\neq 0$.

In the case $p\mid n$, I don't have anything better to say than what Jyrki Lahtonen commented, so I'll just repeat his idea here.  The point is that if $n=pm$, then $x^{n}-d=(x^m)^p-d$ factors as $(x^m-d^{1/p})^p$ (where in fact $d^{1/p}=d$ since $d\in\mathbb{Z}_p$, but that's not important).  So, the distinct roots of $x^n-d$ are the same as the distinct roots of $x^m-d^{1/p}$.  Now if $m$ is still divisible by $p$ you can repeat this process, until you've reduced to the case where $p$ does not divide the degree and you're in the first case.